# asp.net elmah: how to display own error message instead of 'Specified method is not supported'

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I am trying to display "Hello I am testing Elmah" in the Error column of the Elmah Errorlog. I got this in my asp.net app:

```
var customEx = new Exception("Hello I am testing Elmah", new NotSupportedException());
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(customEx);
```

At the moment it comes up with specified method is not supported. How can I change this?

Comment: Are you trying to log using a custom error message whilst retaining the inner exception?